# What is a Surprising Country?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, geography

If a country conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Surprising Country**. If it does not conform to this rule, I call it an **Unsurprising Country**.
Here is a list (not exhaustive) of some Surprising Countries and Unsurprising Countries:

| Surprising Countries | Unsurprising Countries |
| --- | --- |
| BRAZIL | ARGENTINA |
| INDIA | BANGLADESH |
| USA | MEXICO |
| CHINA | MONGOLIA |
| SWITZERLAND | SWEDEN |
| TURKEY | GREECE |
| KAZAKHSTAN | UZBEKISTAN |
| VIETNAM | CAMBODIA |
| MOROCCO | ALGERIA |

CSV version:

```
Suprising Countries,Unsurpising Countries
BRAZIL,ARGENTINA       
INDIA,BANGLADESH   
USA,MEXICO      
CHINA,MONGOLIA         
SWITZERLAND,SWEDEN        
TURKEY,GREECE      
KAZAKHSTAN,UZBEKISTAN    
VIETNAM,CAMBODIA
MOROCCO,ALGERIA
```

Find the rule which determines whether or not a country is surprising.

Comment: Does this follow the What is a Word™/What is a Phrase™ series' typical rules?

Comment: @iBug What do you consider to be the typical rules?

Comment: For example, the obligatory "that each country can be tested for whether it is a Surprising Country without relying on the other countries".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Surprising Country is:

> A country whose **capital city is (*surprisingly*) not its most populous city**.
>
>  Brazil = Brasilia (not Sao Paulo),
>  India = New Delhi (not Mumbai),
>  USA = Washington DC (not New York City),
>  China = Beijing (not Shanghai),
>  Switzerland = Bern (not Zurich),
>  Turkey = Ankara (not Istanbul),
>  Kazakhstan = Nur-Sultan (not Almaty),
>  Vietnam = Hanoi (not Ho Chi Minh City),
>  Morocco = Rabat (not Casablanca).
>
>  For the Unsurprising Countries, their capital cities are also their most populous, which is the most common way of things for countries around the world (and hence *unsurprising*):
>
>  Argentina = Buenos Aires,
>  Bangladesh = Dhaka,
>  Mexico = Mexico City,
>  Mongolia = Ulaan Baatar,
>  Sweden = Stockholm,
>  Greece = Athens,
>  Uzbekistan = Tashkent,
>  Cambodia = Phnom Penh,
>  Algeria = Algiers.

Comment: Damn, that was quick...

Comment: Hey, this was one of the criteria I used for my Connect Wall of Flags!

Comment: @PrinceNorthLæraðr My apologies, I missed the answer to your Connect Wall at the time

Comment: @hexomino Oh, no need to apologize - I didn't mean to sound as though I was accusing you of copying anything. I just thought it was cool that we had a similar idea :)